# How do I play with a full resolution?

Tags: pc, dark-souls

My PC runs at a 1440x900 resolution. In the Dark Souls options page, I do not see that resolution listed.

I tried picking the next resolution down, but it creates black lines at the top and bottom of my game.

How can I play with a full resolution?

Comment: That is an odd resolution... By PC do you mean laptop of some kind? Unfortunately though if you do not see your resolution in the list then you are going to have to deal with black bars :/

Comment: @James It's a pretty common resolution, just a 16:10 ratio.

Comment: Guess I am just not used to seeing <1080 resolutions unless its on a laptop of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A player named Durante has created a mod that will allow you to set a higher/custom resolution. You can download it from [here](http://blog.metaclassofnil.com/?p=108), and follow the instructions in the readme file.

This mod works by intercepting calls to D3D9.dll (Direct3D), changing the resolution in the call, and passing it on to the real D3D9.dll.

Comment: Unfortunately from what I've read, this switches the game to be powered from GPU to now being powered from CPU. My CPU isn't powerful to run this.

Comment: Where are you getting that information? I haven't seen anything like that.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/yqztu/dark_souls_not_utilizing_the_gpu/c5y14hp

Comment: Hm, that's odd. I haven't seen that anywhere else. You might go ahead and try that fix and see if it works for you. If it doesn't, just remove the fix again, and no harm done.

Comment: I tried the patch, but it drops my framerate a lot (like under 15) so I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: And you followed the readme, turning off in-game AA and everything?

Comment: Yeah, I did that before even reading the README. I heard it caused problems and turned it off, first thing.

Comment: Okay. Well, darn, I had hoped that would help.

Comment: Its running great for me. I'm using an intel 2600K.